# Scale up current of a pick and hold solenoid drive IC

Tags: pwm, solenoid

I am trying to help to salvage a design that doesn't meet a new specification.
Circuit needs to drive a solenoid in relatively common fashion: High current pulse to actuate followed by reduced  *hold* current. My colleague designed in a beautiful PWM solenoid driver chip [TI DRV120](https://www.ti.com/product/DRV120) that does exactly what is needed. The caveat is that the achievable **current is about 4x smaller** than needed for the job.

Does anyone have an idea how to boost the current with a minimal number of external components feasible for a rework on the PCBA?

This is the block diagram of the IC:

[image: Detail from DRV120 datasheet]

Basically I am looking for a simple circuit acting as a "current mirror" of kind that would keep 25% of the solenoid current through the chip (to keep the feedback working) and sink 75% of the current straight to GND.
Perhaps a circuit that would work like a PNP BJT with beta=3 as on my napkin sketch:

[image: Concept]

Comment: It is PWM controlled. Looking at the block diagram, Rpeak and Rhold can set the duty to 100%, where the rail voltage decides the load current, unless limited.
Sorry, that I have not read the datasheet through, if you cannot get enough current at 100% duty caused by the driver output, then you may just add another switching FET.

Comment: @jay Thanks for the comment. I certainly studied the datasheet first before posting my question. Perhaps I should have stated that I need about 4x peak current than what the DRV120 is rated for. The max peak current per datasheet is 250mA.

Comment: What is the supply voltage?

Comment: Might be solved by now but check out the DRV110. It's very similar except it allows an external FET

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps a circuit that would work like a PNP BJT with beta=3 as on my napkin sketch:

Beta 3 can be achieved using 3x current mirror, ignore the components value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPswyg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>